# How to remove inline "show" from Google Custom Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the surface this seems pretty simple and I'm not sure why I can't get this right. Basically I'm customizing a google custom search and I need to be able to on load have the input that receives text be hidden until someone clicks on the search icon to make it appear.

That works but I can't get it to toggle back to hidden if the user clicks it again.

I've tried using jquery to toggle a class that changes the display but it doesn't take (presumably because the search is an iframe). So that leaves me with inline display options it seems.

This is what I have so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/tnoqx0fz/28/

**HTML**

```
<div class="google-search">
  <script>
    (function() {
     var cx = '008413334578704215410:ighdkrrioag';
     var gcse = document.createElement('script');
     gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
     gcse.async = true;
     gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
   })();
 </script>
 <gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .google-search {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}
#___gcse_0 {
    width:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:15px;
}
.gsc-control-cse {
    background-color:transparent !important;
    border:none !important;
    width:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
}
.gsc-search-box {
    width:200px !important;
}
.gsc-control-wrapper-cse {
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
}
.gsc-search-box > table {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
#gs_tti50 > input {
    background:none !important;
    text-indent:0px !important;
}
.gsc-search-button-v2 {
    padding:6px 6px !important;
    border: 2px solid !important;
}
.gsc-search-button {
    background-color:#dd2241 !important;    
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    border-color:#fff !important;
}
.show {
    display:block !important;
}
.hide {
    display:none !important;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
      $(".gsc-input-box").css({display: "none"});
      $("#gsc-i-id1").removeAttr('placeholder');
      $("#gsc-i-id1").attr('placeholder', '');
      $(".gsc-search-button").click(function() {
        $(".gsc-input-box").fadeIn(600);
        if ($(".gsc-input-box").css({display: "none"})) {
          $(".gsc-input-box").css({display: "block"});
        } 
        else if ($(".gsc-input-box").css({display: "block" })) {
          $(".gsc-input-box").css({display: "none"});
          $(".gsc-input-box").fadeOut(300);
        } 
        else {
          $(".gsc-input-box").css({display: "none"});
          $(".gsc-input-box").fadeOut(300);
        }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues with your code.

- You were attaching your `click` handler to class `gsc-search-button` but there are 2 elements with that class. The input itself and the `<td>` holding it. Because of this your handler was being called twice the effect of which would hide then instantly show the input again.
- The way your were using jQuery's css was incorrect. You were never checking the `display` your were always setting it.
- The first line of your handler was always fading the input in. So it was always visible when the rest of the code tried to make decisions about it.

I made you a new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8waf311c/1/). This is what I simplified your document ready function to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gsc-input-box").css({
        display: "none"
    });
    $("#gsc-i-id1").removeAttr('placeholder');
    $("#gsc-i-id1").attr('placeholder', '');
    $(".gsc-search-button-v2").click(function() {
        console.log($(".gsc-input-box").css('display'), $('.gsc-input-box').is('visible'));
        //$(".gsc-input-box").fadeIn(600);
        if($('.gsc-input-box').css('display') == 'none') {
            $(".gsc-input-box").fadeIn(600);
        }
        else {
            $('.gsc-input-box').fadeOut(300);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out those few key points! Should have realized that the class getting used 2x would negate what I was trying to achieve.